# Batch script to edit a specific line in a .txt

Tags: batch-file, text

I have this .txt file which contains server properties organized by lines. Example:

```
online-mode=false
level-seed=
prevent-proxy-connections=false
use-native-transport=true
motd=world
enable-rcon=false
server-ip=xx.xx.xxx.xxx
```

The last line of these properties is the server IP.
I need a .bat script which edits specifically the *server-ip* line (i.e. the last line), changing the IP address assigned to it.

How do I make the script know it should edit only the last line?
The only way I could wonder is by creating another .txt containing the text which is not going to change and concatenate it to the IP line on the main .txt, but I think there should be a more optimized way to do this...

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Use a `FOR /F` command to read the file. Use the `delims` option to split the line by the equals symbol.  When the value of the token you want is equal, write out the new line instead of the original.

Comment: Well, there are [numerous similar questions](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bbatch-file%5D+is%3Aquestion+edit+specific+line) on this site…